# how can i add new Object to object with index number

Tags: javascript, object

Is there a way to add the 2 property to the Locations object ?

Property to be added:

```
2:{
   name: "Japan",
   lat: 36, 
   lng: 138,
   description: 'default',
   color: 'default',
   url: 'default'
}
```

Locations object:

```
var locations = {
        0: {
            name: "New York",
            lat: 40.71, 
            lng: -74.0059731,
            description: 'default',
            color: 'default',
            url: 'default',
            size: 'default'
        },
    1: {
        name: "London",
        lat: 51.5073346, 
        lng: -0.1276831,
        description: 'default',
        color: 'black',
        url: 'default',
        type:'square'
        }
}
```

to be like this
locations:{
        0: {
            name: "New York",
            lat: 40.71, 
            lng: -74.0059731,
            description: 'default',
            color: 'default',
            url: 'default',
            size: 'default'
        },
        1: {
            name: "London",
            lat: 51.5073346, 
            lng: -0.1276831,
            description: 'default',
            color: 'black',
            url: 'default',
            type:'square'
            }
        2:{
            name: "Japan",
            lat: 36, 
            lng: 138,
            description: 'default',
            color: 'default',
            url: 'default'
} 
    }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
locations[2] = {
   name: "Japan",
   lat: 36, 
   lng: 138,
   description: 'default',
   color: 'default',
   url: 'default'
}
```